# Как при клике изменить стили dom-элемента?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Работаю с [этой](https://github.com/freestyler-rmg/stiff-chart) библиотекой. К сожалению, между блоками в ней нет отступов, они просто склеиваются(когда перестраиваются друг под друга на маленьком разрешении экрана). Данный плагин представляет собой список и каждый узел это `.stiff-chart-inner li`. Можно ему дать свойство `margin`, или `padding` , однако при клике паутинка, соединящая блоки отступает на указанное арсстояние. Я подумал,что можно было бы дописать js и с помощью jquery обрабатывать клик и во время него убирать отступ. Погугглив написал следующее:

```
$('stiff-chart-inner li').click(function() {
    $(this).css('margin-bottom', '0px');
});
```

Оно не отработало. Возможно я неверно указал селектор. Подскажите пожалуйста как это правильно записать,что оно работало?
Или быть может, в данном случае есть еще какой-то выход(дабы не вткать стили с помощью jquery насильно)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('stiff-chart-inner li')
```

Опечатка тут при переносе кода или у вас такой код написан? Если это класс то надо обращатся с точкой же

```
$('.stiff-chart-inner li').click(function() {
    $(this).css('margin-bottom', '0px');
});
```